# Why can't python find some modules when I'm running CGI scripts from the web?

Tags: python, cgi, bioinformatics, biopython

I have no idea what could be the problem here:

I have some modules from Biopython which I can import easily when using the interactive prompt or executing python scripts via the command-line.

The problem is, when I try and import the same biopython modules in a web-executable cgi script, I get a "Import Error"

> : No
>   module named Bio

Any ideas here?

Comment: Does `import Bio` work in a Python interpreter run from the command line?

Comment: I never had this kind of problem myself. So I can just make guesses. Does your CGI Script call the same python version as you, when you use the python shell? And is your biopython module installed in a way to be used globally, or can it just be that in your shell tests you had a local access to biopython, maybe because you tried it in the biopython folder or something? Hope it is a little bit helpful.

Comment: To Cristian - import Bio does work as executed from the command line or via the interactive interpreter

Comment: Are you using the mod_python module, or real CGI?

Comment: To erkib- biopython is installed along with other modules such as numpy in a site-packages folder, which is not the same as my developing directory.

Comment: To Doug - I am think my answer would be the real CGI . . . I give an "import cgi" at the top of my code, the import error was provided via the cgitb module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple of possibilities:

- Apache (on Unix) generally runs as a different user, and with a different environment, to python from the command line. Try making a small script that just prints out `sys.version` and `sys.prefix`, and compare the result through apache and via the command line, to make sure that you're running from the same installation of python in both environments.
- Is Biopython installed under your home directory, or only readable just for your normal user? Again, because apache generally runs as a different user, perhaps you don't have access to that location, so can't import it.
- Can you try doing `import site` before trying to import Biopython? Perhaps something is preventing site packages from being imported when you run through apache.

Comment: By running sys.version on the interactive prompt, it looks like Apache was running a different version of python than the once accessible from bash. Since I don't have root access, I'm going to try and install biopython locally in my home. Thanks!

Comment: I have apache2 running same python as commandline and this still does not work.  I am using a LAMP VM from GCP.  Wondering what I might have to add to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/lamp-server.conf` to get it to work

Answer (score 4):

In the cgi script, you could try to add the path to this package before any import.

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'path to biopython package')
```

If you are using Apache, you should be able to set the PYTHONPATH in conf file with directive SetEnv

```
SetEnv PYTHONPATH "path to biopython package"
```

Comment: I've tried adding the path by way of "sys.path.insert", the thing is, the containing folder already shows up when I enter "sys.path" into the interactive prompt. I am using apache.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I solved this problem by changing user of Apache in Linux Ubuntu by command in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/envvars
```

**Please change `www-data` on `export APACHE_RUN_USER` and `export APACHE_RUN_GROUP` to your current user or user that can run python script.**
Have a good time ;)

Comment: A much better solution is probably to put the necessary `PYTHONPATH` assignment in there.